# How would i create n no of chunks from an array of dynamic length javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice

I have an array of **n length(dynamic)** say 830... I want this array to be split in sub-array such in the manner **[0,100],[100,200].....[800,829] i.e in equal no of chunks**
How would I execute this??

I have tried below code so far with reference of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

```
var i,j,chunk = 10;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);
 }
```

But As described my **array will be the dynamic** i.e dynamic length if 380. and if no. of a chunk is 100 then have to return 80 at the end

Comment: can you post some examples, of what you've tried so far.

Comment: if you are using "lodash", you can use its `chunk` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
function chunk(orig) {
  var n = Math.floor(orig.length / 100);
  var evenChunks = new Array(n).fill(0).reduce((agg, curr, index) => {
    agg.push(orig.splice(0, 100))
    return agg;
  }, []);

  return [].concat(evenChunks, [ orig ]);
}
```

You can then call like,

```
chunk(new Array(830).fill(0))
```